# Disabled custom order Status Button

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

How to disable Custom order status button  after change the status.

If i click rto button after that button should be disabled?

```
    $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');        
 $block->addButton('Shipement', 
array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipement'), 
'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/shipement')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));          


$block->addButton('rto', 
array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));


$block->addButton('completed', 
array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Complete'), 
'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/complete')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
$order_id=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

if($order->getState() == 'rto')
        {
  $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "", 'class' => 'disabled' ));

          }else {
              $block->addButton('rto', 
 array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
 'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}',        
'{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));


          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just send this   `'disabled' => true` as  function  new parameters to   s second of function *`->addButton()`* parametes  on ***basic on  your  order  custom status*** .

**Just like**

> ```
> $block->addButton('rto', 
>   array(
>       'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
>       'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 
>       'class' => 'go',
>       'disabled'=> $order->getStatus()=='CustomOrderStatus'?true:false
>   )
> );
> ```

It is tested  and work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

please check bellow code:

```
public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $order = $this->_initOrder();
            if (!$order->isCanceled() && $order->canShip()) {
                $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

                $block->addButton('rto', 
                    array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

               $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
            }
        }
    }
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: I already tried this i am using custom order staus if i click rto after change status button also disabled

Comment: right now i have to go and i will search and give you update if possible. i hope this answer lets you little help.

Comment: welcome buddy...